# Rump Kernel Tutorial Don't Know How To Set $OBJCOPY

Tags: unikernel

Here is the link to the tutorial:

https://github.com/rumpkernel/wiki/wiki/Tutorial%3A-Serve-a-static-website-as-a-Unikernel

When I execute the script via ./build-rr.sh hw, I get:

```
/Users/jeffrey/rumprun/buildrump.sh/buildrump.sh: line 1021: type:    objcopy: not found
>> ERROR:
>> cannot find $OBJCOPY (objcopy)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`objcopy` is missing, it is part of [binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/).
You could installed it using :

```
apt-get install binutils
```

or

```
yum install binutils
```